# JaVers and Spring boot 2.1.x [Java 11 version]

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, javers

We are using Javers Auditing framework [5.6.2] in our web application built on Spring boot 1.x. The directions is now to move to Spring boot 2.x and migrate to Java 11. Is there a release planned for this or is the latest current version of JaVers compatible with Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

JaVers is written in Java 8. It means that you can run it safely on JVM 8 or higher (including JVM 11).